# Master Theorem , Polynomial, recurrences

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

Going through Master's theorem for recurrences   but I am seriously confused as what it means when we say that function f(n) is polynomially greater than function g(n) (Case 3) and how can one check for it

Answer (score 0):

It means that the exists some e, strictly greater than 0, such that $\lim \frac{g(n)n^e}{f(n)} = 0$. You can check for it by looking for such an e.